# how to fix that tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api.contrib' has no 'layers' member?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have tried to run code shared on GitHub with my VScode via pylint.

**But I'm getting this error message:**

```
E1101:Module 'tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api.contrib' has no 'layers' member
```

What's the problem here? How can I solve it?

*Here is the code:* 
https://github.com/cj0012/AI-Practice-Tensorflow-Notes/blob/master/opt/opt4_8_forward.py

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: pylint is sometimes wrong. do a test and see if layers exists and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pylint is wrong, the code runs fine. The problem is most likely related to the way TensorFlow generates its API.

Comment: tangential to the original question, but where can I read more on that?

Comment: Do you mean how Tensorflow generates the API?

Comment: @michele-ubik-de-simoni, yes